# Launch interactive OCaml session with library (Yojson) available

Tags: json, ocaml

I've installed the Yojson library for OCaml via GODI:
http://martin.jambon.free.fr/yojson.html

I want to start an interactive ocaml session (i.e. via the ocaml command) and execute functions from the Yojson library e.g.

Yojson.Safe.from_string;;

How do I do this? The above command gives "Error: Unbound module Yojson". I've worked out how to compile via ocamlc with Yojson available, but I want to launch an interactive session instead.

I know this seems like a horrible beginners question but Yojson comes with no samples and minimal instructions so I'm really stumped. I've tried various combinations of "#load" and compiler switches and I'm stuck.

Comment: Don't forget to check out atdgen which takes type definitions and produces the boilerplate code for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tool you are after is called [findlib](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/findlib.html).  It is included in the base GODI installation.  The tools that come with findlib allow you to easily compile against most OCaml libraries and use those libraries from a toplevel session (ocaml).  The findlib documentation is fairly comprehensive, but here is a quick summary to get started.

To start using findlib from within a toplevel session:

```
#use "topfind";;
```

This will display a brief usage message.  Then you can type:

```
#list;;
```

This will show you a list of all of the available packages.  Yojson will likely be among them.  Finally:

```
#require "yojson";;
```

where yojson is replaced by the appropriate entry shown by #list;;.  Yojson's modules should be available for you to use at this point.

Comment: and use ocamlfind for compiling.

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted to compile the file as well though, is this the best way to go about it? I'm confused because I haven't seen "topfind" in other .ml scripts before.

Comment: As Martin Jambon said, ocamlfind is the way to go for compiling.  You would not use the same #use/#require lines though - those are specific to the toplevel environment.